# IOS UIAutomation: app crashes on 'collectionViews.element' with very large amounts of data(cells)

Tags: ios, swift, ios-ui-automation

If collectionView had very large amounts of cells(with scrollView as child) data like "cells().length > 1000(not sure)", then it'll lead to crash when I did something on collectionView' s child element in some cases.

See my codes as below:

```
var myAppWindow = UIATarget.localTarget().frontMostApp().mainWindow();

UIALogger.logMessage(myAppWindow.collectionViews()[0].isVisible()); // >> 1, correctly.

UIALogger.logMessage(myAppWindow.collectionViews()[0].cells().length); // APP CRASHES!!!

UIATarget.localTarget().logElmentTree(); // APP CRASHES!!!

UIALogger.logMessage(myAppWindow.collectionViews()[0].buttons()[0].isVisible()); // APP CRASHES!!!
```

If the length of cells is less than about 200, all will be good.

Let me summerize the CONDITION which will lead to crash:

1. App window has an element tree like: collectionView -> cell -> scrollView
2. A large number of cells.
3. Do some cases on collectionView.

Question:

1. Is that A: an APP issue or B:an UIAutomation issue?
2. If A: How to explain why it's nice by manully?
   If B: How to avoid this CRASH by testing this kind of collectionView? ...

Comment: if your app crashes because of the large number of cell then you should implement pagination, load small amount of record.

Comment: @ Ramani Ashish, Yes, you're right. But cause it crashed by automation-testing, not user action, I don't really want to modify implementation which is related to user experience. Is that possible to optimize the automation script to avoid that?